# Store password in application

Tags: c#, encryption, passwords

A lot of threats talk about how to encrypt passwords, symetric and asymetric encryption etc...

I have a simple probem. If I require the user to type the password every time he wishes to connect to the sqlite database then everything is ok.

**Now the problem is that I want to store the password in the application so that the user does not have to type it every time he wishes to connect to the sqlite database.**

I know I can encrypt the password and store the password encrypted anywhere. But then that means that I will need to store the second password to decrypt that password somewhere else.

I could keep repeating this process and encrypt the second password but then I will be left again with a unencrypted password that I need to unencrypt that password.

So my question is... where should I store that final password that I need to unencrypt other password? where will be the safest place to place that password?

---

If you dont understand the last part, here is an example of what I tried to explain on the last part:

let's say:

password to open database is: `1234`

then I will encrypt that password with the key `someKey` and let's say that gives `abcd`

if I then unencrypt `abcd` with the key `someKey` I should get `1234`

I could encrypt `abcd` again with the key `someKey` and I may get `xy#8`

finally if I will be able to get the `1234` password by unencrypting `xy#8` with the key `someKey` then I will get `abcd` I will then unencrypt that with the same key `someKey` in order to get `1234`

---

so it does not matter how many times I repeat this process I will always end up with some unencrypted key `someKey` somewhere in the application. The only way I will not be required to store that key is if I require the user to provide a password every time he whishes to connect to the database.

where will be the safest place to store the string `someKey` in the application as hidden as possible?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Comment: Why does the database have a password in the first place?

Comment: I want to be flexible with the users using the application. I am required to let them decide wheter the database will have a password, do not have a password or have a password and have the program remember it so that if someone steals the data.db file they will not be able to open it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should encrypt the password using the `ProtectedData` class.
This will have Windows store the key for you.

If you specify per-user encryption and the user has a login password, Windows will use the login password to create its encryption key.

For more info, read about [DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx).